# Много слайдеров на странице

Tags: слайдер

У меня на странице много минислайдеров с элементами с одним классом next и prev, как мне сделать, чтобы учитывался клик внутри конкретного слайдера?

```
var slides = $(".slider .slides").children(".slide");                                                   // Получаем массив всех слайдов
var width = slides.width()+12;      
                                                                                                        // Получаем ширину видимой области
var i = slides.length;                                                                                  // Получаем количество слайдов
var offset = i * width;                                                                                 // Задаем начальное смещение и ширину всех слайдов

$(".slider .slides").css('width',offset);                                                               // Задаем блоку со слайдами ширину всех слайдов

offset = 0;                                                                                             // Обнуляем смещение, так как показывается начала 1 слайд
$(".slider .next").click(function(){
var j=$(this).parent().find('.slides').children(".slide").length - 2;                                                           // Событие клика на кнопку "следующий слайд"
    if (offset < width * j) {                                                                           // Проверяем, дошли ли мы до конца
        offset += width;                                                                                // Увеличиваем смещение до следующего слайда
        $(this).parent().find(".slides").css("transform","translate3d(-"+offset+"px, 0px, 0px)");       // Смещаем блок со слайдами к следующему
    }
});


$(".slider .prev").click(function(){                                                                    // Событие клика на кнопку "предыдущий слайд"
    if (offset > 0) {                                                                                   // Проверяем, дошли ли мы до конца
        offset -= width;                                                                                // Уменьшаем смещение до предыдущего слайда
        $(this).parent().find(".slides").css("transform","translate3d(-"+offset+"px, 0px, 0px)");       // Смещаем блок со слайдами к предыдущему
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что для каждого Вашего слайдера нужно установить так званый `Listener`

```
Slider.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

Но это не точно.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за быстрый отклик!
Разобрался.

```
$(".slider").each(function(){
        var slides = $(this).children(".slides").children(".slide");                                                    // Получаем массив всех слайдов
        var width = slides.width()+12;      
                                                                                                                // Получаем ширину видимой области
        var i = slides.length;                                                                                  // Получаем количество слайдов
        var offset = i * width;                                                                                 // Задаем начальное смещение и ширину всех слайдов

        $(".slides").css('width',offset);                                                               // Задаем блоку со слайдами ширину всех слайдов

        offset = 0;                                                                                             // Обнуляем смещение, так как показывается начала 1 слайд
        $(this).children(".next").click(function(){
        var j=$(this).parent().find('.slides').children(".slide").length - 2;                                                           // Событие клика на кнопку "следующий слайд"
            if (offset < width * j) {                                                                           // Проверяем, дошли ли мы до конца
                offset += width;                                                                                // Увеличиваем смещение до следующего слайда
                $(this).parent().find(".slides").css("transform","translate3d(-"+offset+"px, 0px, 0px)");       // Смещаем блок со слайдами к следующему
            }
        });


        $(this).children(".prev").click(function(){                                                                 // Событие клика на кнопку "предыдущий слайд"
            if (offset > 0) {                                                                                   // Проверяем, дошли ли мы до конца
                offset -= width;                                                                                // Уменьшаем смещение до предыдущего слайда
                $(this).parent().find(".slides").css("transform","translate3d(-"+offset+"px, 0px, 0px)");       // Смещаем блок со слайдами к предыдущему
            }
        });
});
```